# checking for sufficient condition for an unconstrained maximization problem.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mathematica

tried to solve for the max of the following function 
$$ f(s,x,t,y)= \sqrt{\frac{s}{1+s}} + \sqrt{\frac{t}{1+t}} - sx-ty -\frac{50st}{1+x+y}$$ where $ (s,x,t,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{4}$. The function is continuous on the domain and for practical purposes, each of the arguments of the function is bounded above by $ 10^{6} $. Then Weirestrass' theorem guarantees a max but when i used mathematica to check for the second order condition using a hessian, the matrix turns out to be neither positive(semi) nor negative(semi) definite and it seems quite puzzling to me since none of the boundary points are the extrema.
The following are some of the commands i used in mathematica :

hessian[s_, x_, t_, y_] = Function[{f}, D[f, {{s, x, t, y}, 2}]];

f[s_, x_, t_, y_] := "the expression as mentioned above"

D[f[s, x, t, y], {{s, x, t, y}}] // FullSimplify

Solve[{"equating the gradients to zero"},{a,x,b,y},Reals] // FullSimplify

N[%]

hessian[s, x, t, y][f[s, x, t, y]] // FullSimplify ("calculates the hessian at the obtained values")

% /. {{s → 0.05454014415881808`, x → 0.3256826278814554`,
t → 0.05454014415881808`, y → 0.3256826278814554`}} ("these were the values i obtained")

NegativeDefiniteMatrixQ["Plugging in the hessian here"]

this yielded a false result even for negative semi-definiteness, positive definiteness and the associated semi-definiteness. Surely, there must be a max and since it exists, it must satisfy the second order condition since it is an interior point. Could someone please point out the error?

Comment: I have not checked everything, but notice that a continuous function on a compact domain always has a maximum.
This, however, does not imply that the maximum is achieved in an interior point of the domain.
When a maximum is achieved on the boundary, the gradient/derivative need not vanish, and the Hessian/second derivative test need not apply. Trivial examples like $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ easily show this.
When trying to maximize differentiable functions on the boundary, consider using the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit interesting.  At (s,x,t,y)==0, the function value is zero.  For large values of these variables, the function value is negative.  At the stationary point you found, the value is positive at about 1/3, which might suggest the existence of a maximum.  However, setting (x,t,y}=0 and increasing s, we can get as close to 1 as we wish, so it is clearly not a global maximum.  The following plot suggests that you indeed found a saddle.

```
Plot3D[f[s, 0.326, t, 0.326], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image: possible saddle point]